# What is the most efficient 'sparky' way to build a graph from raw data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx, graphframes

I have a dataset containing mentions of various topics across reddit which looks like:

```
    +------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
    | Year_month | Topic | Subreddit | Mention_count |
    +------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
    | 2018_01    | Obama | Politics  |           300 |
    | 2018_01    | Obama | AskReddit |           200 |
    | 2018_01    | Obama | Pics      |           100 |
    | 2018_01    | Trump | Politics  |           500 |
    | 2018_01    | Trump | AskReddit |           150 |
    | 2018_02    | Trump | AskReddit |           180 |
    +------------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

The aim is to build a multigraph where,

- Nodes are topics.
- Edges are created between topics if they co-occur within a subreddit, with the weight being the lowest of the two topic mention counts.

So the above table would create a graph with two nodes, one called *Trump* and another called *Obama*. These would be linked by two edges, one representing co-occurrences within the *Politics* subreddit with weight 300 and another for co-occurrences within *AskReddit* with weight 150.

I usually work in Python/Pandas but this graph is going to contain several million nodes and hundreds of millions of edges so I want to do this in Scala/Spark using GraphFrames.

What is the most efficient Sparky (as opposed to Pythonic) way to build an edge list and then a graph from the above data?

My initial thinking (for one month of data) is to use an inner join to build the edge list like so

```scala
val df_filtered = df.filter($"year_month" === "2018_01")

val df_edges = df_filtered.join(df_filtered, Seq("subReddits"), "inner")
```

which returns

```
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
| Subreddit | Year_month | Topic | Topic | Mention_count | Mention_count |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
| Politics  | 2018_01    | Obama |   300 | Obama         |           300 |
| AskReddit | 2018_01    | Obama |   200 | Obama         |           200 |
| Pics      | 2018_01    | Obama |   100 | Obama         |           100 |
| Politics  | 2018_01    | Obama |   300 | Trump         |           500 |
| AskReddit | 2018_01    | Obama |   200 | Trump         |           150 |
| Politics  | 2018_01    | Trump |   500 | Obama         |           300 |
| AskReddit | 2018_01    | Trump |   150 | Obama         |           200 |
| Politics  | 2018_01    | Trump |   500 | Trump         |           500 |
| AskReddit | 2018_01    | Trump |   150 | Trump         |           150 |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

And then strip out the unneeded information and build the graph with `GraphFrame(v, e)`

While this is concise it seems slow and results in a whole lot of duplicate and redundant rows which could get to be a big problem as the size of the data grows.

What would be the most efficient way to do this? Would it be better to use a for loop or something else?

Also what data type should I be using, Dataframe, RDD, something else?

And finally how should I update with new edges? Do a union of the new edge list to the existing edge list then rebuild the graph?

Thanks!